# Day.js get current date from this week day or what date is this sunday?

Tags: javascript, datetime, dayjs

Using [dayjs](https://day.js.org/) How do you know what date is friday on this week?. Lest say the current start of the week are 14-09-2020 and the end was 20-09-2020, and friday was 18-09-2020.

How do I make a function that return the date of the day that I was looking for? What I'd have tried.

```js
// 5 is for friday the default of dayjs().day(), 0 for monday and 6 for saturday.
function getTheDateonDay(day = 5) {
  const startOfWeek = dayjs().startOf('week') // 13-09-2020
  const getDate = dayjs(startOfWeek).day(day) // invalid
  return getDate
}
```

Comment: invalid? no, it's valid ... for me it results in `2020-09-17T14:00:00.000Z` ... which is `2020-09-18T00:00:00.000` in my timezone since I'm GMT+10 - the issue is, you're mis-interpreting the correct result

Comment: simplest fix, add the dayjs `utc` plugin, and `return getDate.local()`

Comment: Thanks it answer my question why I console logged dayjs object and not strings. https://codepen.io/mandaputra8/pen/QWNrPYR?editors=1011

Comment: sorry, `.local()` should probably be elsewhere in your code `const startOfWeek = dayjs().local().startOf('week')` to make it work for your timezone

Comment: dayjs uses objects, so, look in the documentation to see how to get a string - e.g. `.format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: actually - on reflection, you don't need `utc` at all ... if you just need a string result, then `.format` will do